# Automatic detection and action of unused projects and resources

Tags: amazon-web-services

Our company has reached a point where too many demo projects have been launched and left rolling on their own without having anyone actually assigned to the projects anymore.

**How does one set up something that would detect unused projects/resources and send an email to the owning IAM User?**

It might be fair to assume that *CloudFormation* is being used by almost all the projects (generally through a *CodeStar*, *Elastic Beanstalk*, or *Lambda* set up).

If no reply/activity is manifested by the contacted IAM User, maybe another email could be sent to some administrator notifying about such a situation, too.

Comment: Partial help can come from [rightsizing recommendations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/ce-rightsizing.html) which can identify under-utlizied instances.

Comment: some projects you may be able to fork and work on to produce something that emails users instead of deleting the resources:
https://github.com/codemonauts/aws-springcleaning
https://github.com/rebuy-de/aws-nuke

Answer (score 0):

I have the same need to monitor all ressources used/unused, non compliance ... in my vpc.
I would go to AWS config to , among all feature, get a view of ressources relationship, and [AWS service catalog](https://aws.amazon.com/servicecatalog) to "regroup" authorized ressources and follow a bunch of informations.
Furthermore [AWS config](https://aws.amazon.com/config/) is deploy as a cloud formation stack.

If you dev deploy through cloud formation, you can dig a new feature called [Cloud Formation Hook](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation-cli/latest/userguide/hooks.html) as compliance feature to inspect stack ressource before provisionning, and list all ressource within DynamoDb.

You can check also this ([AWS organizations - List resources by AWS account?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67321347/aws-organizations-list-resources-by-aws-account))

Have a look also [aws-nuke](https://github.com/rebuy-de/aws-nuke) that list ressource - and delete them with the correct quote - for any aws account.