# AWS organizations - List resources by AWS account?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am in charge to clean all unused resources for our AWS organization and I am confused what would be the best strategy.

There is 7 different `accounts` (https://console.aws.amazon.com/organizations/v2/home/accounts)

sharing 454 `resources` in total (https://console.aws.amazon.com/resource-groups/tag-editor/find-resources) across almost every US and EU regions available on AWS

[image]

What is your suggestion to clean resources that are not used anymore? Seems extremely time consuming as there is multiple regions, multiple accounts and so many resources.

Is it possible to get a Map of `account-->resource`? The previous screenshoot is from the `ressource-groups` page but it does not show exactly which resources is attached to which account.

Comment: why dont you use aws config?https://docs.aws.amazon.com/config/latest/developerguide/how-does-config-work.html

Comment: Save your time and use existing libraries, such as: [GitHub - rebuy-de/aws-nuke: Nuke a whole AWS account and delete all its resources.](https://github.com/rebuy-de/aws-nuke)